# How to use existing custom control in my c# project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls, text-editor

I did a lot of research and find a good text editor for c# project. (See the photo below)

[image]

Now i want to use this control in my project But it gives me a lot of errors while it works in dwonloaded project. how can i use this control in my project?

you can download text editor project [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=28226813037563870455) to test

Comment: Soooooo, what are the errors?

Comment: can i create a .dll file from this user control?

Comment: How did you try to use the control in your project, how did you reference it and what are the errors. You need to give us more information.

You can create a dll that contains the control but you don't need to. You can reference any .Net assembly as reference for your project (if the runtimes are compatible)